# Error conexion servidor correo

Tags: php, xampp

Estoy realizando una prueba de envio de correo electronico atravez de un formulario html utilizando un servidor local xampp.
Siendo este el codigo php:

```
//Configuracion del correo electronico
$asunto       =  "Mensaje del formulario";
$destinatario = "andres.mmilagros@gmail.com";

//Recoger los datos del formulario
$nombre  = $_POST["nombre"];
$email   = $_POST["email"];
$cuerpo  = $_POST["mensaje"]; 

//Configurar el remitente como el correo electronico proporcionado por el usuario
$remitente = $email;

// Configurar las opciones de envío
$cabeceras = array(
    'From' => $remitente,
    'Reply-To' => $remitente,
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);


//Enviar el correo
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.example.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", "587");
$retval = mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, '');

echo "asdad";
```

?>

Realize la siguiente configuracion en el archivo php.ini, con la intencion de ejecutar la funcion mail:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.example.com 
smtp_port=585
```

Pero sigo teniendo el error:
`Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.example.com" port 587, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\enviar_formulario.php on line 26`

Comment: Ese error indica que estás intentando conectar con un servidor que no existe... De hecho, smtp.example.com no existe. En esa configuración debes poner un servidor de envío de correo que exista, bien externo o montado por ti

Comment: Ah claro, entendí. Podrias recomendarme un servidor de envio de correo?

Comment: Puedes encontrar varios por internet. Dependiendo del que cojas, necesitarás también configurar usuario y password. Puedes mirar Gmail, sendgrid, MailChimp... O instalarte alguno en el ordenador donde tienes la app, con un docker...